# ng-model return undefined with directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I try to get value from html input tag in a directive, and always get `undefined`,

this is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('templateApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

  $scope.DataList = "";

  $http.post("http://localhost/Service.svc/GetDataMysql", { valval: 0 })
       .then(function (data) {
           if (data.data) {
             $scope.Data = Enumerable.From(data)
                        .Select(function (x) { return x })
                        .ToArray();
             $scope.DataList = $scope.Data[0].Value;
           }
         });
});


app.run(function ($http, $templateCache) {
    $http.get('Template.html', {
        cache: $templateCache
     });
 });

 app.directive('myDir', ['$parse', '$http', '$compile', '$templateCache',      '$location',
    function ($parse, $http, $compile, $templateCache, $location) {
        var linker = function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       element.bind('click', function () {

           var ddd = scope.selectedvalue;
           scope.DataList = Enumerable.From(scope.DataList)
           .Where(function (x) {
               return x.LeafParentId == leafParentId
           }).ToArray()

           $compile(element.contents())(scope);
       });
   };


   return {

       templateUrl: 'Templates.html',
       transclude: true,
       restrict: "E",
       scope: {
           selectedvalue: '=ngModel'
       },

       link: linker
   };
    }]);
```

this is my template:

```
<section ng-controller="Ctrl">
<section class="box1">
    <input type="button" name="" id="1"
           ng-value="checkData(DataList[0].Name)" 
 ng-model="selectedvalue" />             
</section>
<section class="box1">
    <input type="button" name="" id="2"
           ng-value="checkData(DataList[1].Name)" 
 ng-model="selectedvalue" />              
</section>
<section class="box1">
    <input type="button" name="" id="3"
           ng-value="checkData(DataList[2].Name)" 
 ng-model="selectedvalue" />              
</section>
```

and this is my html:

```
  <section data-ng-app="templateApp">
        <div data-ng-controller="Ctrl">

             <ng-dir ></ng-dir>
            </div>


    </section>
```

the directive work fine but when I click on one of the input tags the `ng-model` always returns `undefined`.

```
var ddd = scope.selectedvalue;
```

How can I get the value from the directive input tag?

Comment: Why are you having same ngModel label for 3 different inputs? That is not a right implementation!

Comment: so how can i get the value of the input?